# Adding values dynamically to li

Tags: jquery, html

I want to add values dynamically to a `li` list using jQuery. I'm not able to achieve this using the `each()` method.

```js
$(".dateslots li").each(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    $(li) = i;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="dateslots"> 
  <li class="leftarrow">&nbsp;</li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li class="rightarrow">&nbsp;</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You can see the error in the console. What is `li`? You also cannot set a jQuery object to an integer - that makes no sense whatsoever. If you want to set the text of the element, use the [`text()` method](https://api.jquery.com/text)

Answer (score 2):

I think you are going the wrong way, what you need to use is `.text()` to set a value inside the `li`

```
$(".dateslots li:empty").each(function(i) {
  $(this).text(i)
});
```

You can always remove `:empty` if you want to fill all the `li` with text

**Demo**

```js
$(".dateslots li").each(function(i) {
  $(this).text(i)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="dateslots"> 
  <li class="leftarrow">&nbsp;</li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li class="rightarrow">&nbsp;</li>
</ul>
```